# What to do when java.util is missing on a Mac

Tags: macos, vector, java

This is kind of weired but my Mac/Eclipse isn't offering me any java.util classes. I am still able to run the project which contains heavy use of (let's say) Vector, but I am not able to add a new Vector in the code anywhere.

Eclipse isn't offereing me...

I spent the last night reconfiguering the installed JRE's and build path etc. but it remains ...

I am running Java 1.60 on mac. I tried Eclipse Galielo, Ganymede.

What am I missing?

Comment: As you're using Java 6: is that Sun or SoyLatte? If you're using Sun: so you've got a 64 bit Mac, right? I assume Sun's Java 6 won't run on 32 bit Macs at all, but maybe, just maybe, it might run with all kind of funny side effects...

Comment: ##### SOLVED ##

For the record:

I figured that it was a workspace specific problem. Switching workspace solved the problem. However, since I had my projects in the old workspace that was affected I did the following to -repair- it:

1. Create a new workspace (say workspace2)
2. Make sure/test that this workspace is working correctly by creating a class and let it derive from Vector
3.  Copy .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime folder of workspace2 into workspace1(old workspace)  -> thus replacing this folder
4. Restart Eclipse

Worked for me. No idea what went wrong in the first place

Comment: Thanks everybody for helping me!!

Answer (score 4):

Check that:

- Your source folders are configured property in Project Properties (right click on the project)
- You have a reference to the JRE in the Java Build Path Libraries section of Project Properties and that this is a valid JRE
- You are not missing any JARs on the class path - again these will be flagged up in Project Properties

Also try Cleaning your project and making sure that Build Automatically is on.